# iOS local notification and calendar event does not appear while app is not running

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, localnotification

We'd like to implement silent push in our project, but facing an odd problem!

First, there's a demo project and works fine in my program environment,
but after I apply the same code to my other project, the local notification does not appear after received silent push notification in AppDelegate (something magic) while the app is disconnect with xcode/in background, and there's plan B about calendar, but same as above, therefore, I have no idea to solve, any suggestion?

### 1. silent push notification & local notification demo project

```
 * xcode 10.1, deployment target iOS 10.0

 * objective-c 
 * reference tutorial: https://medium.com/@mikru168/ios-%E6%9C%AC%E5%9C%B0%E9%80%9A%E7%9F%A5-local-notification-b25229f279ec
```

-------> works charme. Local notification appears after receive silent push notification.

### 2. my project + "1."(above code)

```
* xcode 10.1, iOS 9.0
* objective-c mix swift 4.0
```

-------> works fine while debug(connect with xcode), both of while app in foreground and background.

-------> (disconnect with xcode) local notification does not appear while app in background or terminated, but works fine in foreground.

### 3. my project + calendar event

-------> works fine while debug(connect with xcode), both of while app in foreground and background.

-------> (disconnect with xcode) calendar notification does not appear while app in background or terminated, but works fine in foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to share with someone who's stuck this like me,
here's Apple's troubleshooting, and it's really helpful:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

my finally solution is the trigger time beyond 60s.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your given demo and I just added some new methods and code.
It's working for me when an app is disconnected from Xcode.

Please try to add the following methods to your project and test it.

**First of all, please check following services are enabled in your project**

1. Background Modes > Remote Notification
2. Push Notifiation

[image]

[image]

Second, i added this methods in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Also, Added following methods in the appdelegate class

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
     self.addLocalNotification()
    completionHandler(.newData)
}
func addLocalNotification(){
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "title：Test"
    content.subtitle = "subtitle：No---"
    content.body = "body：Silent Notification"
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    // 設置通知的圖片
    let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apple", withExtension: "png")
    let attachment = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: imageURL!, options: nil)
    content.attachments = [attachment]

    // 設置點擊通知後取得的資訊
    content.userInfo = ["link" : "https://www.facebook.com/franksIosApp/"]

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {error in
        print("成功建立通知...")
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and you are right, it should be worked. That is really strange thing on my other project, do you think something settings about compiler that cause unexpected issues (terminated and no local notification pops)?